# How to decrease memory usage from multiple images?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, memory, bitmapimage

My app downloads six images from [here](http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/NCR/) and plays them back in a loop. I download the images in a GIF format, convert them to PNG format using [.NET Image Tools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/), and store each one as a `BitmapImage`, in a `List<BitmapImage>`.

The code I use to add the downloaded image to the list of images is:

```
List<BitmapImage> images = new List<BitmapImage>();
//WebClient used for download

 ...

    GifDecoder decoder = new GifDecoder();
    ExtendedImage eim = new ExtendedImage();
    decoder.Decode(eim, DOWNLOADEDIMAGESTREAM);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WriteableBitmap wbmp = eim.ToBitmap();
            PngEncoder encoder = new PngEncoder();
            encoder.Encode(eim, ms);
            ms.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0;

            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(ms);
            ms.Close();
            images.Add(bmp);
        }
    e.Result.Dispose();
```

Each converted image is about 10- 20 KB, with a size of 600px x 550px. (The original GIF's are about 2/3 the size.)

After downloading the images, my memory usage is around 80 MB. Without downloading the images, the memory usage is around 50 MB. 30 MB Seems like a lot of memory to use for storing six images, with a total size of around 90 KB. In addition, it cuts my framerate down to about 5 or 6, which makes for performance issues when the user zooms or moves my image. (I am not currently displaying the images, just storing them in memory. The image I am using to zoom and move is a test, and was included during **both** of my memory measurements.)

I also wanted to increase the size of the images downloaded, but the amount of memory they already use makes this unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about how big the compressed image is. Once you create a bitmap from it, it's going to be 600x550x (3 or 4, probably, bytes per pixel). So you're looking at over 1MB for each image. In memory they're stored as uncompressed bitmaps. That doesn't account for 30MB, but if you're really concerned about the details of your memory usage, use something like SciTech's .NET Memory Profiler (trial available here: http://memprofiler.com/) and you can find out for sure where the memory is being taken up.

I'm not affiliated with SciTech. I used the profiler a few times over the past decade (including a stretch of a few years where I used it regularly on a project). I've found it to be one of the more accurate methods of determining how memory is used in .NET. Otherwise I find it's a lot of guessing with frequently wrong assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll see if it can provide any help.

Comment: Does it support Windows Phone? I do not see any options for a WP app, and a post on their forums which says they do not support it.

Answer (score 1):

From my view point, we can work around on WP7, because the screen of mobile is small and we cannot display whole content of image as we want. We can download but instead of display original file we should reduce the width and height correct to the screen of mobile phone. Just my two cents.

Comment: I am not actually displaying any of the images I download. Just storing them as BitmapImages.

Comment: Thanks for your info. Because you already post "In addition, it cuts my framerate down to about 5 or 6, which makes for performance issues when the user zooms or moves my image." so that's reason why I answer following that way. Sorry for misunderstood.

Comment: I see where that was confusing. I'll edit it to be more clear.